# IBM IIB 9 multiple data sources

Tags: datasource, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I have message flow with compute node,  which is calling some stored procedure from database.  I set up data source field on this node for db1,  same name exists in odbc.ini file. Now I want dynamically(without redeploying) change datasource to db2. 
For now I've found theese two solutions,  but both of them ugly:

1. Change datasource description in odbc.ini and call mqsireload.
2. Declare user-defined properties for db name and schema,  and call stored procedure like this:

   CALL SOME_PROC() IN DATABASE.{UDP_DBNAME}.{UDP_DBSCHEMA};

Then you can change this properties in runtime using broker API and flow will catch it immediately.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your requirements, you can do something like this:

1. Define both `DB1` and `DB2` in your `odbc.ini` file
2. Create two compute nodes that points to the same ESQL file, but one has the datasource configured with `DB1` and the other with `DB2`
3. Set a new compute node (before the previous two) that contains the logic to determine which one you want to use. `Out1` is connected to `ComputeNodeDB1` and `Out2` is connected to `ComputeNodeDB2`.

With this solution, DB can be dynamically determined during runtime!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to use the PASSTHRU statement to run the database operations.

On that statement you can specify the datasource name so that it is subject to name substitution, which means that it can take the value of a user defined property, which in turn can be modified without stoping the flow.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak05890_.htm